# How can I make 'score record' with database update?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sqlite, record

I'm making millionaire game for my university project and i'm stuck in database part. Game asks the player name before game start. So i record to database as name/money. **I can record the scores. But I want to change record if player(same name login) finish higher than before.** And show this score in a label.(for show to player while he/she playing.) How can I do this? This code is working:

```
public void skorK()
        {

                    string gelenVeri = skor.veri;
                    string dbConnectionString = ("Data Source=sorular.db;Version=3;");
                    SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
                    try
                    {
                        sqliteCon.Open();
                        string Query = ("INSERT INTO skor(isim, puanSkor) VALUES ('" + gelenVeri + "', '" + mevcutPara + "')");
                        SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
                        createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried this. But I'm not even sure that it works. I think it does nothing:

```
string degistir = ("SELECT count(*) FROM skor WHERE isim='" + gelenVeri + "'");
                        SQLiteCommand createCommand2 = new SQLiteCommand(degistir, sqliteCon);
                            int isimDegis = Convert.ToInt32(createCommand2.ExecuteScalar());

                        if (isimDegis > 0)
                        {
                            string degistir2 = ("UPDATE skor SET isim='"+ gelenVeri +"', puanSkor='" + mevcutPara + "'");

                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about implement it just using SQL power? Full command might looks like something below:

```
UPDATE skor SET puanSkor=MAX(puanSkor, @newScore) WHERE isim=@yourPlayerName
```

It can be implemented in c#-code based on [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) injection:

```
string query = ("UPDATE skor SET puanSkor=MAX(puanSkor, @newScore) WHERE isim=@yourPlayerName");
SQLiteCommand updateHighscroeCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, sqliteCon);
updateHighscroeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newScore", mevcutPara);
updateHighscroeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourPlayerNam", gelenVeri);
updateHighscroeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Using Parameters collection is a good practice that prevents security problems and makes code bit more structured. You can learn more examples in [ado.net tutorials](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06).